# I am trying to loop a Python script 50 times but I'm only getting one line of output in my file

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I want to loop the following code 50 times, so I'm using the range function. When it runs, the output file only has 1 row of data in it.

I've gotten the code to run successfully without the looping portion. It provides me with a table of data.

What I want to do now is to loop the code 50 times and write the last row of each iteration to a new dataframe.

- Ideally, I don't even want that much data. I just need the value in the 'Period' field in the last row of each iteration.

If someone could help me see what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy_financial as npf
from datetime import date, datetime
from numpy import random

for x in range(50):
        #np.round(df, decimals=2)
        interest=0.04125
        years=2
        payments_year=12
        mortgage=40000
        start_date=(date(2023, 2, 1))
        #additional_pmt = np.random.randint(2100, 4500, size=len(df))

        initial_pmt = -1 * npf.pmt(interest / 12, years * payments_year, mortgage)
        initial_ipmt = -1 * npf.ipmt(interest / payments_year, 1, years * payments_year, mortgage)
        initial_ppmt = -1 * npf.ppmt(interest / payments_year, 1, years * payments_year, mortgage)
        print('Initial Payment: {:,.2f}'.format(initial_pmt))
        print('Initial Interest: {:,.2f}'.format(initial_ipmt))
        print('Initial Principal Payment: {:,.2f}'.format(initial_ppmt))


        # Create date range in pandas dataframe
        rng = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=years * payments_year, freq='MS')

        # label the date column
        rng.name="Payment Date"

        # create dataframe
        df=pd.DataFrame(
            index=rng,
            columns= ['Org Total Payment',
                      'Total Payment',
                      'Interest',
                      'Principal',
                      'Additional Payment',
                      'Org Ending Balance',
                      'Ending Balance'], dtype='float')
        # set index as payment period
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df.index += 1
        df.index.name="Period"

        # Create values for the first period
        period=1
        additional_pmt = np.random.randint(2100, 4500, size=len(df))

        # for each element in the row set the value
        initial_row_dict = {
            'Org Total Payment':initial_pmt,
            'Total Payment': initial_pmt + (additional_pmt),
            'Interest': initial_ipmt,
            'Principal':initial_ppmt,
            'Additional Payment': additional_pmt,
            'Org Ending Balance': mortgage - initial_ppmt,
            'Ending Balance': mortgage - initial_ppmt - (additional_pmt)
        }

        # set values
        columns = list(initial_row_dict.keys())
        period_values = list(initial_row_dict.values())
        df.at[period, columns]= period_values

        # add additional rows
        for period in range(2, len(df) + 1):
            #get prior period values
            previous_total_payment = df.loc[period - 1, 'Total Payment']
            previous_principal = df.loc[period - 1, 'Principal']
            previous_org_ending_balance = df.loc[period - 1, 'Org Ending Balance']
            previous_ending_balance = df.loc[period - 1, 'Ending Balance']
            #get end balance
            period_interest = previous_org_ending_balance * interest / payments_year
            period_principal = initial_pmt - period_interest
            additional_pmt = np.random.randint(2100, 4500) + 400
            org_ending_balance = previous_org_ending_balance - period_principal
            ending_balance = previous_ending_balance - period_principal - additional_pmt

            row_dict = {'Org Total Payment':initial_pmt,
                        'Total Payment': initial_pmt + (additional_pmt),
                        'Interest': period_interest,
                        'Principal': period_principal,
                        'Additional Payment': additional_pmt,
                        'Org Ending Balance': org_ending_balance,
                        'Ending Balance': ending_balance}
            columns = list(row_dict.keys())
            period_values = list(row_dict.values())
            df.at[period, columns]= period_values

df_mask=df['Ending Balance']>=0
filtered_df = df[df_mask].round(2)
storage_df = pd.DataFrame()
last_row = filtered_df.tail(1)
storage_df = storage_df.append(last_row, ignore_index=True)

print(storage_df)
storage_df.to_csv('allruns.csv')
```

Comment: You are creating a brand new `df` in every loop, efficiently discarding anything you had created before.  If you need to accumulate data, you have to create the `df` OUTSIDE of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried moving my for x in range (50) code to right below the section where I create the dataframe. I still only get 1 row of data.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do here.  Each run of the loop overwrites the same parts of the df.  You aren't appending anything here.  And `storage_df` is always going to be the last row and only the last row.  When the loop is done, you create it, you append one row to it, and you save it.

Comment: I'm terrible at loops. What I'm trying to do is create a new data frame with each run of the loop and append the last row to storage_df. I'll then output the results of storage_df to a csv for further analysis. Thanks again for taking the time to help me.

Comment: If you want `storage_df` to accumulate, then you need to initialize it BEFORE the loop, and you need the four lines that append to it to be INSIDE the loop.  Right now, neither thing is true.  You want until the loop is done, then you create `storage_df` and append one line to it.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Tim Roberts. His help got me to the solution. Here's the final code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy_financial as npf
from datetime import date, datetime
from numpy import random

storage_df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(50):
        #np.round(df, decimals=2)
        interest=0.04125
        years=1
        payments_year=12
        mortgage=40000
        start_date=(date(2023, 2, 1))
        #additional_pmt = np.random.randint(2100, 4500, size=len(df))

        initial_pmt = -1 * npf.pmt(interest / 12, years * payments_year, mortgage)
        initial_ipmt = -1 * npf.ipmt(interest / payments_year, 1, years * payments_year, mortgage)
        initial_ppmt = -1 * npf.ppmt(interest / payments_year, 1, years * payments_year, mortgage)
        #print('Initial Payment: {:,.2f}'.format(initial_pmt))
        #print('Initial Interest: {:,.2f}'.format(initial_ipmt))
        #print('Initial Principal Payment: {:,.2f}'.format(initial_ppmt))


        # Create date range in pandas dataframe
        rng = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=years * payments_year, freq='MS')

        # label the date column
        rng.name="Payment Date"

        # create dataframe
        df=pd.DataFrame(
            index=rng,
            columns= ['Org Total Payment',
                      'Total Payment',
                      'Interest',
                      'Principal',
                      'Additional Payment',
                      'Org Ending Balance',
                      'Ending Balance'], dtype='float')
        # set index as payment period
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df.index += 1
        df.index.name="Period"

        # Create values for the first period
        period=1
        additional_pmt = np.random.randint(2100, 4500, size=len(df))

        # for each element in the row set the value
        initial_row_dict = {
            'Org Total Payment':initial_pmt,
            'Total Payment': initial_pmt + (additional_pmt),
            'Interest': initial_ipmt,
            'Principal':initial_ppmt,
            'Additional Payment': additional_pmt,
            'Org Ending Balance': mortgage - initial_ppmt,
            'Ending Balance': mortgage - initial_ppmt - (additional_pmt)
        }

        # set values
        columns = list(initial_row_dict.keys())
        period_values = list(initial_row_dict.values())
        df.at[period, columns]= period_values

        # add additional rows
        for period in range(2, len(df) + 1):
            #get prior period values
            previous_total_payment = df.loc[period - 1, 'Total Payment']
            previous_principal = df.loc[period - 1, 'Principal']
            previous_org_ending_balance = df.loc[period - 1, 'Org Ending Balance']
            previous_ending_balance = df.loc[period - 1, 'Ending Balance']
            #get end balance
            period_interest = previous_org_ending_balance * interest / payments_year
            period_principal = initial_pmt - period_interest
            additional_pmt = np.random.randint(2100, 4500) + 400
            org_ending_balance = previous_org_ending_balance - period_principal
            ending_balance = previous_ending_balance - period_principal - additional_pmt

            row_dict = {'Org Total Payment':initial_pmt,
                        'Total Payment': initial_pmt + (additional_pmt),
                        'Interest': period_interest,
                        'Principal': period_principal,
                        'Additional Payment': additional_pmt,
                        'Org Ending Balance': org_ending_balance,
                        'Ending Balance': ending_balance}
            columns = list(row_dict.keys())
            period_values = list(row_dict.values())
            df.at[period, columns]= period_values
            df_mask=df['Ending Balance']>=0
            filtered_df = df[df_mask].round(2)
            last_row = filtered_df.tail(1)
        storage_df = storage_df.append(last_row, ignore_index=True)

storage_df.to_csv('allruns.csv')
```